# A bounded linear operator on $L^{2}$

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a quesiton about a bounded linear operator and so on.

Let $(E,\mathcal{B},m)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $G$ be a bounded linear operator on $L^{2}(E;m)$.

We assume the follwing condition:

$(1)$ $D(G)=L^{2}(E;m)$

$(2)$ $G:D(G)\to L^{2}(E;m)$ is injection

$(3)$ For all $f \in L^{2}(E;m)$ with $0\leq f \leq 1$ $m$-a.e. $\Rightarrow$ $0 \leq Gf \leq 1$ $m$-a.e.

By using the condition $(3)$, I can prove "for all $f \in L^{2}(E;m)$ with $ f\geq0 $ $m$-a.e. $\Rightarrow$ $ Gf \geq0 $ $m$-a.e."

Since $(E,\mathcal{B},m)$ is $\sigma$-finite, there exists a function $\phi \in L^{2}(E;m)$ so that $\phi>0$ $m$-a.e. Then $G \phi >0 $ $m$-a.e. is true?

I think condition $(2)$ is effective... (  $Gf=0$ $m$-a.e. $\Rightarrow$ $f=0$ $m$-a.e. )

Comment: what IS the question?

Comment: For $\phi$ as above, $G \phi >0 $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the shift $G$, defined by $\ell^2 \ni  a = (a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots) \mapsto (0,a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots) = Ga \in \ell^2$. Then $G$ satisfies all assumptions and $\ell^2$ is $\sigma$ finite with respect to the counting measure. But for any  sequence $a \in \ell^2$ that is positive everywhere, $Ga$ is zero on a set of positive measure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is there counterexamples...